# File is interpreted as a variable

Tags: postgresql, debugging

Wrote and tested a pretty simple script in SQL. Now I need to get it working in Postgres (which I'm just learning). Can't figure out the latest error. The script is reading a file to be a variable. Perhaps I'm not using DBeaver correctly (which I'm also trying to learn).  Basically, when data is over 90 days old, move date from transactions to archive_transactions and delete change_log records. The error and code is below:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: "archived_transactions_prerun" is not a known variable
  Position: 325
```

CODE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Archiving ()
RETURNS void AS $$

declare 

BEGIN

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Archived_Transactions_PreRun;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Change_Log_PreRun;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Transactions_PreRun;
--COMMIT;

SELECT *
INTO Archived_Transactions_PreRun
FROM Archived_Transactions;

SELECT *
INTO Change_Log_PreRun
FROM Change_Log;

SELECT *
INTO Transactions_PreRun
FROM Transactions;

COMMIT;

-- Create reporting table entries
----------------------------------

DECLARE YYYY_MM_DD  DATE = (SELECT CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE()))     -- Run Date
  , Report_Date DATE = (SELECT DATEADD (DAY, -90, GETDATE())) -- 90 Days ago
  , To_Archive  FLOAT
  , Chg_Log     FLOAT;

-- Count records to be archived
-------------------------------

SET Chg_Log    = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Change_Log WHERE date_updated < Report_Date);
SET To_Archive = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transactions WHERE date < Report_Date);

-- If nothing to archive, exit 
------------------------------

IF Chg_Log    > 0
OR To_Archive > 0;
BEGIN

-- Remove 90+ records from change_log
-------------------------------------

DELETE
  FROM change_log
 WHERE date_updated < Report_Date;

-- Copy 90+ records to Archived_Transactions
--------------------------------------------

INSERT INTO Archived_Transactions
SELECT *
  FROM Transactions
 WHERE [date] < Report_Date;

-- Remove 90+ records from transactions
---------------------------------------

DELETE
  FROM Transactions
 WHERE date < Report_Date;
COMMIT;
END;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
COST 100
```

Comment: There are a whole lot of issues with this code. I would spend some time [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html). Hint, your use of `COMMIT` is wrong. The error is because `SELECT INTO` has a specific [meaning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) in `plpgsql` and you have declared the variable `Archived_Transactions_PreRun`. Also I would lose the mixed case names they will only cause you issues, unless you want to quote them all the time.

Comment: That should have been: you have **not** declared the variable `Archived_Transactions_PreRun`.

Comment: And you mix code and declarations and `SET` is not for assignment. In short, this code has little to do with PL/pgSQL, and you are advised to read the documentation to understand the syntax.